# Linq join query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

For example 
DB with 2 Tables

```
Book [BookId (int), Title (nvarchar), ShowInWebshop (bit)] and 
InventoryDetail [InventoryDetailId (int), BookId (int), Quantity (int)]
```

Execute: `SELECT * FROM Books LEFT JOIN InventoryDetails ON books.BookId = InventoryDetails.BookId`

The output shows all Book columns and related InventoryDetails columns (including the InventoryDetails.BookId column) 
..so far so good ...
Trying to transform this query into a Linq one (using LinqPad, comparing several examples, common sense, etc.) I compilated the following generic List (because I wanted a present a list)

```
private List<Book> Books(int count){
    var books = webshopDB.Books
        .Join<Book, InventoryDetail, int, Book>( webshopDB.InventoryDetails, 
            b => b.BookId, 
            i => i.BookId,
            (b, i) => b )
        .Where(b => b.ShowInWebshop == true)
        .Take(count)
        .ToList();
    return books
}
```

This module returns a list of books! Not the one I expected, though! It returns only book details such as Title and ShowOnSite NOT the details from the InventoryDetail table: Quantity

What do I forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The result how it works so far ...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{                
    // This return a list of tuples {(WebshopDB.Models.Book, WebshopDB.Models.InventoryDetail)}
    // Each tuple containing two items: 
    // > Item1 {WebshopDB.Models.Book}
    // > Item2 {WebshopDB.Models.InventoryDetail}
    var tuple_books = ListOfTuples_BookInventoryDetail(5);
    ...
    // next step(s)
    // add a ViewModel viewmodel
    // ...
    return (viewmodel);
}

private List<Tuple<Book, InventoryDetail>> ListOfTuples_BookInventoryDetail(int count)
{
   var list_of_tuples = new List<Tuple<Book, InventoryDetail>>();

   var showbooks = webshopDB.Books
     .Join(webshopDB.InventoryDetails, b => b.BookId, i => i.BookId, (b, i) => new { b = b, i = i })
     .Where(o => (o.b.ShowInWebshop == true))
     .Where(o => o.b.BookThumbUrl.Contains(".jpg"))
     .OrderByDescending(o => o.b.OrderDetails.Count())
     .Take(count);         

  foreach (var item in showbooks)
  {
    list_of_tuples.Add( Tuple.Create<Book, InventoryDetail>( (item.b), (item.i) ) );
  }
  return list_of_tuples;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from both tables, e.g.

```
from b in webshop.Books
from i in webshopDB.InventoryDetails
where i.BookId = b.BookId
select b.BookId, b.Title, b.ShowInWebshop, i.InventoryDetailId, i.Quantity
```

Comment: Quering your answer generates errors! The following works (in LinqPad4): from b in Books
from i in InventoryDetails where b.BookId == i.BookId where b.ShowInWebshop == true select new { b.Title, i.Quantity }

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Sorry for the oversight; I did not have LinqPad or another development tool handy at the time I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting books because you specified that in your `Join` statement with the final selector of `=> b`. You want to select both, so use this:

```
var query = webshopDB.Books.Join(webshopDB.InventoryDetails,
                  b => b.BookId, i => i.BookId,
                  (b, i) => new { Book = b, InventoryDetail = i });
```

Then when you iterate over the results you can use:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Book.SomeProperty);
    Console.WriteLine(item.InventoryDetail.SomeProperty);
}
```

The other problem with your method is that the return type is a `List<Book>`. So the above won't work since a `Book` class is separate from an `InventoryDetail` class. You need to setup a new class to encompass both, or use a `Tuple<Book, InventoryDetail>` if using .NET 4.0.

To return a particular property you could modify the statement to:

```
var query = webshopDB.Books.Join(webshopDB.InventoryDetails,
                  b => b.BookId, i => i.BookId,
                  (b, i) => new { b.BookId, i.Quantity });
```

Again, you need an appropriate return type if you're returning a `List<T>`.

EDIT: to get a `Dictionary<Book, InventoryDetail>` you could use the earlier query as follows:

```
var query = webshopDB.Books.Join(webshopDB.InventoryDetails,
                  b => b.BookId, i => i.BookId,
                  (b, i) => new { Book = b, InventoryDetail = i })
              .ToDictionary(o => o.Book, o => o.InventoryDetail);
```

Of course you can use the `Where` and `Take` as necessary before the `ToDictionary` call. You can also project just the properties you need as the query just before this one. You need to project it into an anonymous type via the `new` keyword (it was missing earlier so take another look at it).

Comment: @user507458: I was missing the `new` keyword earlier. Take a look at my edit above for a `ToDictionary` solution. Bear in mind this will only work if you have unique keys. Also you'll need to change your return type to `Dictionary<Book, InventoryDetail>` or whatever types you decide to return.

Comment: Hi Ahmad Mageed, 
Meanwhile, I only managed to return a Tuple type by use of method Tuple.Create<Book, InventoryDetail>(book, inventorydetail) :). 
However, it returns only the last record in the database. So, I have to figure out how to get all the 'book' and 'inventorydetail' out. Especially, if I want to add an extra join (for instance to  OrderDetail as well).

Therefore, I implemented the Dictionary return type one (THX for your gracious help).

Comment: So the question remains: How to get the object Book (as key) and object InventoryDetail (as value) out of the dictionary (or in case of a Tuple: the items) and properly store them into a ViewModel?

Comment: @user507458 once you perform the join you would add a final `Select` statement to project the results and create the Tuples as you described if you decide to go that route (easy way to avoid duplicate keys). If you're only getting the last result check the `join` statement alone and check it's `Count()` to verify. I can't help with the ViewModel question since I'm currently not familiar with ASP.NET MVC. You may want to ask a new question specifically about that issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Quering the answer of SoftwareRockstar in LinqPad4 generates errors! So, that's not the way!

```
//This does works (in LinqPad4)    
from b in webshopDB.Books 
from i in webshopDB.InventoryDetails
where b.BookId == i.BookId
where b.ShowInWebshop == true 
select new { b.Title, i.Quantity, b.ShowInWebshop }
```